# Import jar to lucene ant build script

Tags: java, ant, lucene, guava

I'm having trouble including the guava (http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library in my ant build script for lucene (lucene-3.5.0/build.xml). I'm trying to build the demo with the addition specified in the answer to this question: [Detect duplicate English names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814190/detect-duplicate-english-names/8844516#8844516)

I have been able to successfully include the library in a standalone project

I get the error:

> common.compile-core:
>       [javac] Compiling 2 source files to /Users/seb/lucene-3.5.0/build/contrib/demo/classes/java
>       [javac] /Users/seb/lucene-3.5.0/contrib/demo/src/java/org/apache/lucene/demo/NameDuplicateTests.java:17:
>   package com.google.common.collect does not exist
>   [javac] import com.google.common.collect.HashMultimap;

I have added the jar file to my classpath via

> export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/$HOME/guava-10.0.1.jar

and made a similar change to /System/Library/Java/JavaConfig.plist

I have added the following to lucene-3.5.0/build.xml

```
<!-- Build classpath -->   <path id="classpath">
<pathelement location="${build.dir}/classes/java"/>
<pathelement location="$HOME/guava-10.0.1.jar"/>   </path>
```

I have the correct include statements in my java file, eg.

```
import com.google.common.collect.HashMultimap;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Ant docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html).

You can access environment variables by passing them in using `-D` or the [property task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html).

You may also define the full path to the library in the build file itself.

As it stands, your script has no idea what `$HOME` is.